# WooCommerce - pay order with multiple payment methods at same time

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to know if there is a way to customize WooCommerce such that the clients could pay the same order with multiple payment methods at the same time?

For example, if one order is worth $100, I want to allow clients to pay $25 with a Visa card, then $75 with a Discover card. So the general idea is to pay one order (don't checkout multiple times), but use more than just one payment method.

I assume there is some way to personalize something, but I want to know where/how to get started with it.

**EDIT 1**
Just adding a new payment gateway (custom) does not solve the issue. I know how to create a custom payment gateway.

The issue is: *how do I allow on ONE checkout for ONE order to get the payment out of 2 or more sources at the same time? For example: $175 cashed in as $50 PayPal + $100 Visa + $25 MasterCard.*

There are many clients who would love to have this option, and pay with more cards at the same time!

So, this is not one of those obvious questions as **how do I create a custom payment gateway?** - that is something easily achievable without spending too much time on it. The multiple payment on same checkout, however, proves to be lengthy / not discussed (I've researched many articles, forums, etc.)

Comment: I suggest you look at an existing payment methods gateway class. For example: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/gateways/bacs/class-wc-gateway-bacs.php

This has all the hooks you need to do what you need.

Comment: I know that I can create/replicate payment gateways and add them all as custom gateways. The problem is still this: how can one order take 2-3 payment methods at the SAME time? The client should never have to make 2-3 orders, but have 1 order, add all payments (imagine $50 PayPal $100 Visa $25 MasterCard or any other combinations) upon finishing checkout. I did not see a way to do that, as everything is made in a way to allow people to pay with ONE method, out of N methods. I want them to pay with M methods at the same time out of the installed N methods.

Comment: This is a custom gateway. With hooks you can do what ever you want. You could redirect them to another endpoint which accepts credit card details then redirect to PayPal, then even some left over to pay by cash. You would just need to register a new order status of partially paid.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this challenge?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution or even a concrete direction for this?

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create a custom payment gateway, and in that gateway, create interfaces for ALL the payment methods you want to use.

I would say use something like Stripe for all the CC and then PayPal - that way you will have only two separate ones to handle.

You need to put in an option to pay X amount on each payment gateway on the Checkout screen.

Then in your plugin when someone partially pays, create a coupon for the amount of the partial payment using the Coupon API and apply that.

You will also need an Order Status of Partial Payment or something.  You would also need to redirect back to the Checkout page if the order isn't completely paid, instead of the Order Success page.

It's pretty complicated to do this right.